# Dropdownlist in gridview not firing selectedindex changed event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have problem with not firing selected index changed event of dropdownlist in gridview. I gone through the [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485390/why-isnt-the-selectedindexchanged-event-firing-from-a-dropdownlist-in-a-gridvie) . It is not worked wholly for me. I have implementation like below.

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Review" Value="Review" Selected="True">Review</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Level1" Value="lvl1">Send Back to Level1</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind the GridView to something.
       DataBindGrid();
  }
 else {
    // Bind the GridView again to maintain previous entered data in the gridview
       DataBindGrid();
  }
  }

  protected void DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this.lblCity.Text = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
  }

protected void grdPoll_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DDL1") as DropDownList;
      if(ddl != null)
      {
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i keep  `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` block only then it works fine. But i want `else` block also.  Whats going wrong with implentation. Can you please suggest the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is block after !Page.IsPostBack block, which is not event else part as you said. You are binding grid again on post back which results in loss of the event being fired. You do not have to bind it again to have the changes in the grid.

Remove this code.

```
{
   // Bind the GridView again to maintain previous entered data in the gridview
   DataBindGrid();
}
```

Comment: I want to bind it again on postback where i am assigning different updated datasource to gridview

Comment: Then you should bind it in some event instead of Page_load could be in DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind the GridView to something.
       DataBindGrid();
  }
 else {
    // Bind the GridView again to maintain previous entered data in the gridview
       //DataBindGrid(); //remove DataBindGrid(); from else
  }
}

protected void DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.lblCity.Text = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
     DataBindGrid();
}
```

Comment: remove DataBindGrid(); from  DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged event and caode put in if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind the GridView to something.
       DataBindGrid();
  }
 else {
    // Bind the GridView again to maintain previous entered data in the gridview
       DataBindGrid();
  }

Answer (score -1):

replace event name "Page_Load" with "Page_PreRender"